# How to make just one or more threads in a process stop consuming CPU resources?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, linux-kernel

Is there a way to make one or more threads in a process stop consuming CPU resources while the other threads in this process can still consume CPU resources?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach this is by remembering that in Linux, Threads are just processes sharing their memory. Therefore, other threads in your process are also considered processes. I'd then look for a `cgroups2` solutions to add it to a CPU resource process group.

You can look for tutorials for it here:  [Theory](https://lwn.net/Articles/679786/) [Practice](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-moving_a_process_to_a_control_group)